# Filebeat is not forwarding the logs to Elasticsearch service in AWS

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, filebeat, aws-elasticsearch

I created a ElasticSearch service in AWS and using filebeat as deamonset in my kubernetes setup to forward the logs.

Below is my deamonset yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      containers:
      - name: filebeat
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.3.2
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
          "-e",
        ]
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: ${elasticsearch_host}
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "443"
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 256Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: filebeat.yml
        - name: inputs
          mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/inputs.d
          readOnly: true
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: filebeat-config
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      - name: inputs
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: filebeat-inputs
      # We set an `emptyDir` here to ensure the manifest will deploy correctly.
      # It's recommended to change this to a `hostPath` folder, to ensure internal data
      # files survive pod changes (ie: version upgrade)
      - name: data
        emptyDir: {}
```

Deamonset  is running fine in K8s. I don't see any error but I am not getting any logs in ELK. while I am checking Kibana. I am getting this msg.

[image]

I was using the same filbeat yaml template for other environment its working but when I just created a new Elasticsearch service and using the new endpoint to forward the logs Its not working. I have also attached the description of deamonset. I don't see any events there. Could it might be the issue??

[image]

Comment: As i can see from the picture, the elasticsearch service created inside a vpc, make sure you can reach it

Comment: @AmitBaranes yes. it's reachable.